# Does $E[XY|Z]=E[XY]$?

Tags: probability, expectation

Assume $E[X|Z]=E[X]$. Assume $Y$ and $Z$ are independent. Does $E[XY|Z]=E[XY]$? Can you prove it?

My intuition says $E[XY|Z]=E[XY]$ but expanding the expectations into integrals I couldn't prove it.

Comment: Your "intuition"?? Really? Could you expand on this?

Comment: can you write down what you had in terms of "expanding into integrals"?

Comment: @Did My intuition: If $(X,Y)$ are independent of $Z$ then $E[XY|Z]=E[XY]$ so my intuition was that as long as one of them is independent of $Z$ and the other was mean independent then we are okay... come to think of it if $E[X|Z]=E[X]$ and $E[Y|Z]=E[Y]$ then this does not imply $E[XY|Z]=E[XY]$... so maybe that intuition is wrong.

Comment: This is probably wrong, but doesn't $E[X|Z]=E[X]$ tell you that $X$ and $Z$ are independent?

Comment: @CalvinLin \begin{align*}
E[XY] &= \int \int xyf_{X,Y}(x,y)dx dy\\
 &= \int \int xyf_{X|Y}(x)f_{Y}(y)dx dy\\
 &= \int \int xyf_{X|Y}(x)f_{Y|Z}(y)dx dy\\
 &= \int y f_{Y|Z}(y) \int xf_{X|Y}(x) dx dy 
\end{align*}
hmmmm... I was hoping to eventually get this to equal $E[XY|Z]$ but I seem to be stuck.

Comment: @FlybyNight No, for example $E[X^2|Z]$ may not equal $E[X^2]$. The assumption that $E[X|Z]=E[X]$ is known as $\textbf{mean}$ independence.

Comment: @FlybyNight Example: $X=UZ$ with $U$ centered, square integrable, independent  of $Z$, then $$E(X|Z)=E(U)Z=0=E(U)E(Z)=E(X)$$ and $$E(X^2|Z)=E(U^2)Z^2\ne E(U^2)E(Z^2)=E(X^2).$$ This case can be used/adapted to answer the main question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not true. We will find a counterexample using a suggestion by @Did to show that $E[XY|Z] \neq E[XY]$.

Let $X=UZ$ and $Y=U$ with $U \sim Unif(-1,1)$ independent of Z, then $Y$ and $Z$ are independent and $E[X|Z]=E[UZ|Z]=ZE[U]=0$. But, $E[XY|Z]=E[ZU^2|Z]=ZE[U^2]=Z/3$ and $E[XY]=E[ZU^2]=E[Z]/3$.